# Connecting the old router to the main router

Tags: networking, router, ip, wireless-router, dhcp

I have **Calix 854G-2** as my main router (with IP: **192.168.1.1**), and **Netis WF2419**, the old router that I want to connect with main router **via wireless** (not able to connect them with cable). In the DHCP settings of the main router I set the beginning IP **192.168.1.3** and ending IP **192.168.1.254**, so I can give the old router unique IP **192.168.1.2**. (check the screenshot)
Main router, DHCP settings

[image: screenshot Main router, DHCP settings]

I access the old router from my PC with LAN cable, through IP **192.168.1.1** to connect it to main router: **WAN type - Wireless**, found the wifi signal from my main router and connected to it: (check the screenshot)

Second router, WAN connection settings

[image: Second router, WAN connection settings]

Then, I went to LAN setting of the old router to set the IP to **192.168.1.2** and **disabled DHCP**. So now it looks like this: (check the screenshot)

LAN settings of old router

[image: LAN settings of old router]

I click **Save & Reboot**, the router restarts, and when it's back on and I do the IP config in CMD, the IP address of old router is **192.168.0.1** (??)

check the screenshot:

[image: Old router with questionable IP address]

So now I can access:

- main router from **192.168.1.1** address
- second router from **192.168.0.1** address

The second router works with this configuration, gives me a good connection, but after a day it somehow breaks, gives me no connection and I can't access to it from IP **192.168.0.1**. Until I reset it to factory settings and do all of this all over again...

Does anyone has the idea how to configure it correctly, and why the old router gives itself this IP 192.168.0.1 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, to sum up the problem if I read that correctly. You are setting router-2 to the 192.168.1.x subnet and it reboots with it's default ip address space? This is either a firmware caveat, or a hardware issue. (NV_RAM failure). See if you can find updated firmware for router-2, it may resolve this issue. It may be worth it to try another browser, like internet explorer in compatibility mode. Some older devices and their web guis do not play well with newer browsers.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And the router-2 is not even resetting itself on default IP - it changes the IP to 192.168.0.1 ... When I reset it to factory settings, the IP is 192.168.1.1.

I updated the firmware before I tried all of this...

Comment: That's even more Goofy. Try with I.E or another browser that supports compatibility modes. Or a non-ideal approach, change router-1 to the 192.168.0.x space instead.